# What audio interface is this?

Tags: audio, audio-interfaces

just a short question.

What audio interface is being used on this video ?

I can`t find it anywhere, I have search though everything on http://www.thomann.de/ but I can`t it find anywhere. It seems to be some kind of multitrack recorder.

Cheers

Comment: I just *so* want to say "it's called a telephone" :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a Digidesign 003, discontinued and no longer supported.